# How to send a plain text mail using AWS SES to gmail

Tags: python, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a formatted file, with padding strings, when I send it to my account in gmail, all the paddings in the file are deleted and the mail is not well formatted because gmail does not keep the original format. 
What to do to avoid this ?

I tried this code, but it is not working using Raw email :

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
from email import encoders

fileHandler = "logg.log"
session = Session(profile_name="test", region_name="eu-west-1")
ses = session.client('ses')
today = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
for file in sorted(glob.glob(fileHandler + '*'), key=os.path.getmtime):
    body = MIMEText(open(file, 'r').read())
    body['Subject']="aws-log"
    response = ses.send_raw_email(
                            Source = "smymail@.com",
                            Destinations=[
                                    "smymail@fluksaqua.com",
                                ],
                            RawMessage={
                                'Data': body.as_string()
                                    },)
```

Even by using raw mails, the mail does not come in plain text.

Here is the file I send to gmail :

[image]

This is the mail I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem, this guy `<pre></pre>` saved me!! Here is how:

```
body = '<pre width="300" style="font-size: 14px; max-width: 100%;">' + body + '</pre>'
            subject = objet+" %s" % (today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
            for email in emailarg.split(','):
                response = ses.send_email(
                            Source = email,
                            Destination={
                                'ToAddresses': [
                                    email,
                                ],
                            },
                            Message={
                                'Subject': {
                                    'Data': subject
                                },
                                'Body': {
                                    'Html': {
                                        'Data': body
                                    },
                                }
                            }
                        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need `send_raw_email`. If you take a look at the [`send_email`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email) method it actually takes both `Text` and `Html` body arguments:

```
Message={
    'Subject': {
        'Data': 'string',
        'Charset': 'string'
    },
    'Body': {
        'Text': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'string'
        },
        'Html': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'string'
        }
    }
}
```

If you just supply a Text body that should get you the plain-text email you're looking for.

As far as gmail plain text formatting they will wrap lines at 78 characters as per RFC 2822 section 2.1.1:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822

This is an accepted standard for plain text emails. You could format the message yourself for plaintext but it would have to adhere to a 78 character limit per line to avoid reformatting.

Comment: In fact, I know that HTML can resolve my problem, but I don't want to use it because otherwise the mail will be huge and very charged. I'm really stuck how to send well formatted text to gmail. :/ Thank you @DaveMaple for the help

Comment: You can just leave out the Html in 'Body' -- only supply an argument for 'Text'.

Comment: Yes I know. I only give Text, but it is not raw. When I get the mail, it is reformatted by gmail..

Comment: Oh -- I'm sorry. I see now. This is a question about how to work around gmail's formatting of plain text messages. Are your lines longer than 78 characters? Can you post a sample of your raw body and a screenshot of how it comes through in gmail?

Comment: The lines are very long. more than 78 characters

Comment: Updated answer to explain the potential issue with lines exceeding 78 characters. Ultimately, an HTML email is going to be the right solution for the formatting you're looking for.

Comment: Is it a solution to encode the body in Quoted-Printable ? as said in here [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text) @Dave

Answer (score 0):

Look more closely at your received email.

Copy its body out and paste it into a text editor.  You should find that the spaces are in fact perfectly correct.

The issue here -- I believe -- is not with SES.

The issue is that Gmail's UI displays plain text emails in a proportional typeface, instead of a fixed-width typeface.  Note how IIIIII takes up less horizontal space than WWWWWW even though the number of characters is the same.  This naturally destroys formatting with spaces.  Conversely...

```
# IIIIII - code blocks on SO
# WWWWWW - use a fixed width typeface
# even though the rest of the post doesn't
# so I and W are the same width here but not above
```

If you want control over the display, you'll need to use HTML and specify a fixed-width typeface.

Comment: I know but are we sure there is no other way or solution other than HTML ? :/ @Michael